# Combining Stash lists

Tags: stash

I'm still new to Stash and still in the process of wrapping my head around it. I'm developing a music site which will have four total channels.  On the homepage, I'll have a main section with the mix of all channels sorted by date. Then below that i'll have columns that will display a single channel (with entries that may already be included in the main section)

My question is, how do I combine all the channels together into the one section. I would've thought using a pipe character would work like this, but that didn't work:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="news_home|reviews_home|gallery_home"}
```

Example :

```
{!-- APPEND LIST --}
    {!-- GALLERY --}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" require_entry="yes" status="open" limit="7"}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="gallery_home" parse_depth='2'}
            {stash:home_title}{title}{/stash:home_title}
            {stash:home_image_gallery}{gallery_thumbnail}{/stash:home_image_gallery}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {!-- REVIEWS --}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="reviews" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" require_entry="yes" status="open" limit="7"}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="reviews_home" parse_depth='2'}
            {stash:home_title}{title}{/stash:home_title}
            {stash:home_content}{content text_only="yes"}{/stash:home_content}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/exp:channel:entries}

    {!-- NEWS --}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" require_entry="yes" status="open" limit="7"}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="news_home" parse_depth='2'}
            {stash:home_title}{title}{/stash:home_title}
            {stash:home_content}{content text_only="yes"}{/stash:home_content}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- GET LIST --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="news_home|reviews_home|gallery_home" parse_tags="yes" limit="7" parse_conditionals="yes"}    
                <div class="box {switch='one|two|three|four|five|six|seven'}" ><a href="/{home_short_name}/{home_url_title}" title="{home_title}"><h2>{home_title}</h2></a></div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```